# Javascript gracefully degrade a whole div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So on the page I have a div that's part of the layout.
The div contains JS stuff, so although it's part of the layout, there's no point in showing it if there's no Javascript.

Now I would normally put this in `<head>`:

```
<style> div#target{ display:none } <style>
<script> $(document).ready(function(){ $('div#target').show(); }); </script>
```

But my boss wants that div during page load.
So I have to resort to something ugly in `<body>`:

```
<style> div#target{ display:none } <style>
<div id="target">stuff in div</div>
<script> $('div#target').show(); </script>
```

Which is invalid xHTML, has some IE drawbacks I heard, and most of all it just sucks.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave the `<style>` element in the head.

There is nothing invalid about having a `<script>` as a sibling element to a `<div>`

---

You could be more efficient with:

```css
div#target{ display: none }
body.js div#target{ display: block }
```

and

```
<body>
<script> document.body.className += " js"; </script>
```

---

That said, if an element is only relevant if JS is available, then it usually makes sense to add it using JavaScript instead of trying to hide it if JS isn't available.